# Exception when trying to create an elastic pool on azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net

I need to create programmaticaly an elastic pool. Here is my code :

```
        var credentials = new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(await GetToken());

        var sqlclient = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.SqlManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

        var sqlServer = (await sqlclient.Servers.GetWithHttpMessagesAsync("MyApp-com","myApp-com")).Body;

        var azurePool = (await sqlclient.ElasticPools.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync("MyApp-com",sqlServer.Name,"poolname", new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models.ElasticPool(sqlServer.Location,  edition:"Basic",dtu:5))).Body;
```

I'm using :

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources" Version="2.20.1-preview" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql" Version="1.6.0-preview" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" Version="3.3.10" />
```

I'm getting this exception on the last line:

```
Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Invalid value for header 'x-ms-request-id'. The header must contain a single valid GUID.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.ElasticPoolsOperations.<BeginCreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.ElasticPoolsOperations.<CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

And as you can see here, 'x-ms-request-id' is NOT a valid guid ( but RequestId property is ):[image]

Could you help me with this please ? Is the library not yet stable for CRUD ?

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167981/azure-fluent-api-error-creating-sql-server-missing-x-ms-request-id-header

Comment: Thank you sir, I have already seen that question but because I don't have ApplicationInsights I tolad myself that It's maybe something else, I'll add a comment in this question to mention that even if you don't have AppInsight, it can cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also can reproduce it with .net core 2.0. And we also could use the way that mentioned in the another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167981/azure-fluent-api-error-creating-sql-server-missing-x-ms-request-id-header) to solve it,even we don't have application Insights. More details please refer to the [blog](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/disable-application-insights-correlation-id-headers-on-httpclient-requests-in-aspnet-core/). In your case we need to change dtu to equal or larger than **50**, for basic version at least **50** dtu. Following is my detail steps:

1.Create .net core 2.0 Asp.net project.

2.Add the following code in the **Startup.cs** file.

```
 private void DisableCorrelationIdHeaders(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var module = services.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ImplementationFactory?.GetType() == typeof(Func<IServiceProvider, DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>));
            if (module != null)
            {
                services.Remove(module);
                services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryModule>(provider => new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule { SetComponentCorrelationHttpHeaders = false });
            }
        }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            DisableCorrelationIdHeaders(services);
        }
```

[image]

3.We need to change the dtu to **50** for basic version.

```
var azurePool = (await sqlclient.ElasticPools.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync("MyApp-com",sqlServer.Name,"poolname", new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models.ElasticPool(sqlServer.Location,  edition:"Basic",dtu:50))).Body;  //at least 50 for basic version
```

4.Test it locally,it works correctly on my side.

[image]

5.Check from the Azure portal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the error messages on the API's are a bit misleading.

Have you tried setting eDTU to 50?

This is the minimum eDTU's you can use for the Basic Tier you're trying to create:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

Comment: I also have mentioned this in my answer. You also could comment on this.