# .NET Core 2.1 C# Get an azure SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, azure, .net-core

I am trying to get a DB from Azure on a .NET Core 2 app. I am able to get the DB Server with the following code:

```
IAzure azure;
azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription();
ISqlServer sqlServer = azure.SqlServers
    .GetById("MyServerDBId");
```

The problem I have is when I try to retrieve the Database. With the following code:

```
ISqlDatabase dbFromSample = sqlServer.Databases.Get("MyDbName");
```

I get the exception:

> Invalid value for header 'x-ms-request-id'. The header must contain a
>   single valid GUID.

If I try to list the database to verify the if the information is correct (with `sqlServer.Databases.List();`) I get the same exception.
And with the following code:

```
ISqlDatabase dbFromSample = sqlServer.Databases.GetById("5");
```

I get the following exception:

> The specified ID 5 is not a valid Azure resource ID.

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167981/azure-fluent-api-error-creating-sql-server-missing-x-ms-request-id-header#45180204

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but it didn't changed the result

Comment: I have reviewed the question one more time and found that I was applying the solution wrong. It solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Cool good to hear :)